# VirtualBox kernel modules will not load via systemd

Tags: fedora, virtualbox, kernel-modules

I am using akmods from RPMFusion for VirtualBox. The packages listed by `rpm -qa` are:

```
kmod-VirtualBox-4.6.4-301.fc24.x86_64-5.0.24-1.fc24.x86_64
VirtualBox-5.0.24-1.fc24.x86_64
VirtualBox-kmodsrc-5.0.24-1.fc24.x86_64
akmod-VirtualBox-5.0.24-1.fc24.x86_64
```

Further, the modules are built and located in the correct directory:

```
/usr/lib/modules/4.6.4-301.fc24.x86_64/extra/VirtualBox/vboxdrv.ko
/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/90-vboxdrv.rules
```

I omitted `vboxguest`, etc. I can manually load the modules with `modprobe` and it displays with `modinfo`:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/4.6.4-301.fc24.x86_64/extra/VirtualBox/vboxdrv.ko
version:        5.0.24_RPMFusion r108355 (0x00240000)
license:        GPL
description:    Oracle VM VirtualBox Support Driver
author:         Oracle Corporation
srcversion:     0D9059DC39F24CF9E36EA61
depends:        
vermagic:       4.6.4-301.fc24.x86_64 SMP mod_unload 
parm:           force_async_tsc:force the asynchronous TSC mode (int
```

The problem is that it will not load via `systemd`:

```
● systemd-modules-load.service - Load Kernel Modules
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-modules-load.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2016-07-24 16:09:50 EDT; 5s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-modules-load.service(8)
           man:modules-load.d(5)
  Process: 3961 ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-modules-load (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 3961 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

`journalctl _PID=3961` shows:

```
Failed to insert 'vboxdrv': Operation not permitted
```

And so on and so forth.

I've tried everything on the Internet but they don't seem to be related to my problem:

- The old modules are not being loaded
- They are not located in my initramfs
- I will not switch to Oracle's repo because that's missing the point
- I will not use DKMS because that's missing the point, and doesn't do anything by itself since RPMFusion doesn't do DKMS
- I do not have SecureBoot. My motherboard does not even support it.
- `akmods --force` shows `Checking kmods exist for 4.6.4-301.fc24.x86_64             [  OK  ]` and that's it. `depmods -a` runs and looks like it's doing something but doesn't solve my problem.
- I have completely wiped the packages and reinstalled them, but it doesn't fix the problem. `/var/cache/akmods` show that the modules are being built against the correct kernel module as demonstrated anyways, so I'm convinced the problem is related to `systemd`.

My NVIDIA kernel module is loading just fine.

It may or may not be related but shutdown takes forever. If I hit <kbd>F12</kbd>, I see "Running stop job for Building.. akmods service" and it takes a 1 minute and 30 seconds before my computer shuts off. `systemd-analyze critical-chain` shows thjat most of the time is spent in `systemd-user-sessions.service @35.189s +178ms`. `systemd-analyze blame` shows `13.548s akmods.service`.

I've checked RedHat bug reports and have not been able to decipher them. Please try to avoid giving common solutions found in forums on the Internet because rest assured, I've tried them.

Comment: What is the output of `modprobe -v vboxdrv`?  That will see if the module can be loaded at all, and give a clue of what is going wrong.

Comment: @grochmal `insmod /lib/modules/4.6.4-301.fc24.x86_64/extra/VirtualBox/vboxdrv.ko` As I stated in my question, `modprobe` works fine. The issue seems to primarily be related to `systemd`.

Answer (score 3):

Turn off the **secure boot** option from the BIOS settings then try to sign the driver following  the steps described [here](http://gorka.eguileor.com/vbox-vmware-in-secureboot-linux-2016-update/)